# Как реализовать проверку на нажатие кнопки в новосозданном канале?

Tags: python, discord, disnake

В моём Discord-боте реализована некая система ивентов. При выборе ивента для запуска из списка (эту функцию вставлять не буду, так как в ней нет смысла). После выбора элемента из списка идёт handler-обработчик. В нём я создаю необходимые переменные, а так же создаю 2 канала - информация и управление. В информацию я отправляю информацию об ивенте, соответственно.
Вся проблема кроется в канале управления, куда я отправляю сообщение с кнопками. При нажатии на кнопку я получаю ошибку 404 Interaction Not Found. До этого, когда меню управления отправлялось в канал отправки команды - всё было хорошо.
Сам свою проблему я понимаю - мой цикл проверяет канал отправки.

**Вопрос:** как мне переписать/изменить код так, что бы обработчики нажатий на кнопки работали в другом канале (control_channel)? *Надо учитывать, что мне нужно передавать все переменные, такие как event, event_channel и так далее для последующей передачи их в функции-обработчики кнопок*

Функция запуска ивента:

```
async def handle_event_start(self, interaction, event):
action_guild = get_group(interaction.guild.id)

components = [
    disnake.ui.Button(style=disnake.ButtonStyle.gray,
                      label='Замутить всех', custom_id='mute_all'),
    disnake.ui.Button(style=disnake.ButtonStyle.gray,
                      label='Размутить всех', custom_id='unmute_all'),
    disnake.ui.Button(style=disnake.ButtonStyle.gray,
                      label='Кикнуть с ивента', custom_id='kick_user'),
    disnake.ui.Button(style=disnake.ButtonStyle.red,
                      label='Завершить ивент', custom_id='stop_event'),
]

start_time = time.time()
kick_users = []

embed = disnake.Embed(
    title='Запуск ивента', description=f'<@{interaction.author.id}>, идёт процесс  **создания** ивента...', color=0x973ab7)
await interaction.message.edit(embed=embed, components=[])

category = await interaction.guild.create_category(f'＃{event.name} | {interaction.author.name}', position=0)
info_channel = await interaction.guild.create_text_channel("┌・информация", category=category)
control_channel = await interaction.guild.create_text_channel("└・управление", category=category)
event_channel = await interaction.guild.create_voice_channel(f'・{event.name}', category=category)

link = f"https://discord.com/channels/{interaction.guild.id}/{event_channel.id}"
link_button = disnake.ui.Button(
    style=disnake.ButtonStyle.link, label='Присоединиться', url=link)

embed.description = f'<@{interaction.author.id}>, вы успешно запустили ивент «**{event.name}**».\nКанал управления: <#{control_channel.id}>.'
info_embed = disnake.Embed(
    title=f'Запущен новый ивент - {event.name}!', description=f'**Описание ивента:** {event.description}', color=0x973ab7)
info_embed.set_footer(text=f'{interaction.guild.name} · {datetime.fromtimestamp(int(time.time())).strftime("%d.%m.%Y - %H:%M")} | Ведущий: {interaction.author.name}',
                      icon_url=interaction.guild.icon.url if interaction.guild.icon else interaction.author.default_avatar.url)

control_embed = disnake.Embed(
    title='Управление ивентом', description=f'<@{interaction.author.id}>, используйте этот канал в качестве управления ивентом.\nНачало ивента: **{datetime.fromtimestamp(int(time.time())).strftime("%H:%M:%S")}**.')

await info_channel.send(f'<@&{action_guild.events_notify_role}>', embed=info_embed, components=[link_button])
await control_channel.send(embed=control_embed, components=components)
await interaction.message.edit(embed=embed, components=[])
await interaction.response.defer()

while True:
    try:
        interaction = await self.bot.wait_for('button_click', check=lambda inter: inter.user.id == interaction.user.id)

        if interaction.component.custom_id == 'mute_all':
            await handle_mute_all(interaction, event_channel)
            continue

        elif interaction.component.custom_id == 'unmute_all':
            await handle_unmute_all(interaction, event_channel)
            continue

        elif interaction.component.custom_id == 'kick_user':
            await handle_kick_user(self, interaction, event_channel, kick_users)
            continue

        elif interaction.component.custom_id == 'stop_event':
            await handle_stop_event(interaction, event, event_channel, start_time, kick_users)
            continue

    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await interaction.message.edit(embed=embed, components=[])
```

Comment: https://guide.disnake.dev/interactions/buttons

Comment: @Axaneron было бы так просто, я бы не задавал вопрос. Ссылка на документацию с 1 примером не решило мою проблему.

Comment: Я это скинул к тому, что не надо использовать ```bot.wait_for```, есть более нормальные решения. Это и не ответ, а просто комментарий

Comment: @Axaneron поэтому и скинул свой код, чтобы доброжелатели помогли сделать код более "гуманным"